# Two sites with the same postal address both getting indexed for the keywords on one of the sites

Tags: seo, keywords, google-index, search, search-results

I have developed two websites with different domain names that are hosted on two different servers: Site-A and Site-B.  Everything is different between the two websites, but only the geographic postal addresses are same.  The differences:

- Services provided
- website design
- structure
- colour
- domain names

One site is providing web development services, and other is providing diesel generator installation services. But these are two different services provided at one location (address).

After these sites were indexed, I noticed that Site-B is indexed for Site-A keywords. That is, if I search for Site-A in Google, then Site-B is also indexed in search results.

I have integrated these two websites with Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools accordingly.  What could be causing the cross indexing?

Comment: Have you double-checked your web server configuration to make sure that everything is correct- meaning that you are not serving the wrong content for each domain name? As well, check to see what site, it any, comes up when referencing by IP address. It should not be either if you host more than one site on a server. Most people have catch-all sites set-up to handle IP only requests. This can be as simple as a single page with a link to both sites. I am thinking it is server-side.

Comment: On the Google Webmaster Tools site, go to Crawl -> 'Fetch as Google' to see how Google sees your page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Submit the second one in google webmaster tools
2. Resubmit sitemap in GWT
3. Check all pages with "fetch as googlebot" and send them to index
4. Set craw rate to maximum
5. [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/add-site.html)